# Completely remove .Net 3.0 install

Tags: .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do I do if .NET Framework is not installing?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1834/what-do-i-do-if-net-framework-is-not-installing)

Trying to install .Net framekwork 3.5 but it complians that 3.0 is not present.

However, when trying to install 3.0: the installer complains that 3.0 is in fact installed.

- Add/Remove programs doesn't list 3.0 (When I tried to uninstall it, I got a message saying the install program coulnd't be found and did I want to remove it from Add/Remove programs, I said yes).
- I'm sure this is registry problem but I can't find any associated keys.

Any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT: **Solved** I ran the ".NET cleanup tool" found from this question: [What do I do if .NET Framework is not installing?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1834/what-do-i-do-if-net-framework-is-not-installing)

So, since this question is essentially a duplicate, shoudl I delete it or wait for an admin to close it?

Comment: What OS are you on?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the upgrade for the .NET Framework?

**EDIT**
Try running the .NET cleanup tool.

Comment: This is the answer from your post.  No reason to delete the question as its always good to have a different question that leads you to the answer.

Comment: Agreed.  Tho it'll probably save someone some time if you notch an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As the 3.5 SP1 installer contains 2.0 and 3.0 that shouldn't be needed anyway... have you tried the full offline setup instead of the bootstrapper (which only downloads what it thinks you need)?

Comment: yes I have, but no luck